INGRESS - Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" (...)
This is amy LAB system - I am learing about ingress.

I deployed the basic/default IngressController:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.12.0-beta.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

I tried to deploy Ingress.
I took example from here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource



apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx <--- readjusted the name to fit with ingressClass from IngressController
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80


Sadly, I am getting the following error which is not clear to me.
Can anybody help me to troubeleshoot what is the problem?
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.107.59.228:443: connect: connection refused

